# adjusting canvas to fit screen on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a canvas element dynamically created which overlays every other element. On resize, the canvas fits to the screen perfectly without any trouble.
I figured that the same principle would work with scrolling, but it does not:

```
    var a = document.createElement('canvas');
    createCanvas();
    function createCanvas(){
        a.height = $(window).height();
        a.width = $(window).width();
        a.id = "some_canvas";
        a.style.opacity = "0.8";
        a.style.position = "absolute";
    document.body.insertBefore(a,document.body.firstChild);

    context = a.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = "#000000";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, a.width, a.height);   
}

$(window).resize(function(){
    $("some_canvas").remove(); 
    createCanvas();
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
   $("#some_canvas").remove();
   createCanvas();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9mfxytoz/1/

the canvas remains at it's last size adjustment, but does not follow through with scrolling. I'm trying to make it so that the canvas can always be seen, even when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<canvas id="Canvas2D"></canvas>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#Canvas2D {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

And here is the JS required to make it all work:

```
// set the width and height to the full windows size
var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
// Change to scroll height to make it the size of the document
var SCREEN_HEIGHT = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;

// Make sure to set the canvas to the screen height and width.
canvas.width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
canvas.height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;

// everytime we resize change the height and width to the window size, and reset the
// center point  
window.onresize = function () {
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = canvas.height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    SCREEN_WIDTH = canvas.width = document.body.offsetWidth;    
    HALF_WIDTH = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
    HALF_HEIGHT = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I just looked at the question that this was the original answer to. Seems like there was an issue with the scrolling in that as well though.

Comment: @NOFNe didn't get you??